# Accessing directories outside of DocumentRoot

Tags: .htaccess, httpd.conf, virtual-directory

I've recently deployed a web application to my Linux Redhat server using [Capistrano](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=capistrano&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Documentation-v2.x&ei=IPNCT4OPDpLt8QOPiPWyCA&usg=AFQjCNHYgsI46jRT8tbmE8Cl-b7u-jK54Q&sig2=3JG7In9AknaVdjuiCF_M4w) which creates the following directory structure in the site's document root:

```
/var/www/html/example.com/releases/*
/var/www/html/example.com/current
```

In order to load the current directory on page load, I changed my httpd.conf so that example.com's DirectoryRoot was set to `/var/www/html/example.com/current`.  The problem is that I want certain directories to be available for browsing which are outside the 'current' directory (phpMyAdmin and Bugzilla).  I've tried `touch`ing a .htaccess file to `/var/www/html/example.com` but nothing is created...

What do I need to do in order to access directories which are located outside my DocumentRoot?  Should I change the DocumentRoot and use .htaccess to forward the web browser to my current directory, or is there a better approach?

Also, as an unimportant side issue: is it wise to use a specific port for certain services?  When I used cPanel, they used :2082 and WHM used :2086.  Could I do a similar thing on my server to make the services (phpMyAdmin and Bugzilla) a little more hidden?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to want to use an [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) to give access to directories outside you current DocumentRoot.

Apache's config is actually pretty well self-docuemnting. You can use the alias for `/icons/` as an example:

```
# Aliases: Add here as many aliases as you need (with no limit). The format is
# Alias fakename realname
#
# Note that if you include a trailing / on fakename then the server will
# require it to be present in the URL.  So "/icons" isn't aliased in this
# example, only "/icons/".  If the fakename is slash-terminated, then the
# realname must also be slash terminated, and if the fakename omits the
# trailing slash, the realname must also omit it.
#
# We include the /icons/ alias for FancyIndexed directory listings.  If you
# do not use FancyIndexing, you may comment this out.
#
Alias /icons/ "/var/www/icons/"

<Directory "/var/www/icons">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

> Also, as an unimportant side issue: is it wise to use a specific port for certain services? When I used cPanel, they used :2082 and WHM used :2086. Could I do a similar thing on my server to make the services (phpMyAdmin and Bugzilla) a little more hidden?

You could, but that's just security through obscurity you best bet is to serve them over SSL and require a username/password combination.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. I'm a programmer by trade -- always been a bit reluctant to dabble with server configs, but this was actually quite easy. As you said, it's very well documented.

Comment: instead of setting up an apache Alias, could a dev just symlink to a folder outside of DocumentRoot before hand? like 'ln -s /uploaded_files  /var/www/html/myproject/public/uploaded_files'